# How to handle a collision and move player back to original position? [c++, sfml]

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

So, I'm creating a game and I just started working on the collision system.
The detection is finished, but I can't figure out how to move the player back to his last position (before he collided).

Just doing `player.x--` won't work since he could come from the other side of the x axis and so on (pretty obvious), so how would I make the player move back 1 pixel, no matter "where" he collides with a entity?

Hopefully this made sense, my math and English isn't very good. :P

Comment: might be better answered on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the last position and then use it.